# How to pass params to the sign in google provider

Tags: reactjs, next.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, next-auth

I've been trying to fix this for 10 hours, reading the github issues, the docs, but nothing seems to help. i have a simple page where the user log in using his google account. i just want to pass a role parameter to the google client sign in api function and access it in the sign in callback. here's what i mean

```
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
const handleGoogleSubmit = async () => {
    /// tried this from the doc but didn't work
    const res = await signIn("google", null, { role: "admin" });
  };
return (
               <Button
                  intent={"socialGoogle"}
                  className={"w-full"}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    handleGoogleSubmit();
                  }}
                  icon={<GoogleBrandDefault />}
                >
                  Continue with Google
            </Button>
)
```

my [...nextauth] file where i 'd like to access the param HERE

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      if (account.provider === "google") {
        // HOW TO ACCESS IT HERE ?
        return true;
        
      }
    },

    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`;
      else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url;
      return baseUrl;
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
    
      return token;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

PLEASE HELP ME OUT !

here's the link to the doc by the way
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#additional-parameters